# waiting for async funtion to finish

Tags: asynchronous, flutter

I want to read some txts and store their text in an array. But because I need this array for my GUI it should wait until all is done.

```
Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }

  int topicNr = 3;
  int finished = 0;
  for (int topic = 1; topic <= topicNr; topic++) {
    getFileData('assets/topic' + topic.toString() + '.txt').then(
      (text) {
        topics.add(text);
      },
    ).whenComplete(() {
      finished++;
    });
  }

while (finished < topicNr)
```

But when I run this code, finished won't update (I think because it is because the while loop runs on the main thread and so the async funtion can't run at the same time)

I could do this by just waiting, but this isn't really a good solution:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigation Basics',
      home: MainMenu(),
    ));
  });
```

How can I now just wait until all of those async Funtions have finished?

(sorry, I am new to Flutter)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use a stateful widget and a loading modal. When the page is initialized, you set the view to be the loading modal and then call the function that gets the data and populate the data using set state. When you are done/when you are sure the final data has been loaded then you set the loading to false. See the example below:

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  page();
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _Page();
}


class _Page extends State<Page>{

 bool _loading = true; //used to show if the page is loading or not

   @override
  void initState() {
  getFileData(path); //Call the method to get the data
  super.initState();
  }

  Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path).then((onValue){
        setState(() { //Call the data and then set loading to false when you are done 
      data = on value.data;
      _loading = false;
    });
   })
  }


  //You could also use this widget if you want the loading modal ontop your page.
  Widget IsloadingWidget() {
    if (_loading) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          new Opacity(
            opacity: 0.3,
            child: const ModalBarrier(
              dismissible: false,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor:
                  new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
              strokeWidth: 4.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
//If loading, return a loading widget, else return the page.
       _loading ? 
       Container(
         child: Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
             Colors.blue))))
       :Column(
        children:<Widget>[
         //Rest of your page.

      ]
      )      
    ]))
}

}
```

You could also set the fields of the initial data to empty values and the use set state to give them their actual values when you get the data.
so for example

```
string myvalue = " ";

   @override
  void initState() {
  getFileData(path); //Call the method to get the data
  super.initState();
  }



//then  
  Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path).then((onValue){
        setState(() { //Call the data and then set loading to false when you are done 
      data = on value.data;
       myValue = onValue.data['val'];
      _loading = false;
    });
   })
  }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: But if I understand it right, there would be a problem with the //Call the data and then set loading to false when you are done, because I am calling this method multiple times?

Comment: If you are calling it multiple times, what you can do is setlonading to be false when the final async method is called.

Comment: But what will then happen if the first one finished earlier than the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FutureBuilder` to wait for the API call to complete before building the `widget`.

See this example: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

```
runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: 'Navigation Basics',
  home: FutureBuilder(
     future: getFileData(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
         return MainMenu()
       } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
       }
));
```